# Como extraigo los datos de un promise

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

estoy desarrollando un proyecto con angular, el asundo es que en una clase tengo el siguiente metodo, el cual devuelve una promesa de un string:

```
registrarCliente(cliente: Cliente): Promise<String> {
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    return this.http.post("/api/taller/cliente/", cliente, options).toPromise().then(this.extractData);
}
//extrae el contenido del response
private extractData(res: Response) {
    let body = res.json();
    return body || {};
}
```

Luego en otra clase quiero extraer el string de esa promesa, por lo que tengo el siguiente codigo:

```
    this.mensaje = this.clienteService.registrarCliente(cliente);
    this.mensaje.then(response => {
        alert(response);
    }).catch(e => {
        console.log(e);
    });
```

Sin embargo, nunca me muestra el alert con el String y cae en el catch.
PD: tengo muy poca experiencia en este tema, si pueden ser claros al explicar seria de gran ayuda :D

----Agrego---
Con el console.log del error me muestra:

```
Object {
 _body: "<!DOCTYPE html>\r\n<html lang=\"es\" xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\">\r\n    <head>\r\n        <meta charset=\"utf-8\" />\r\n        <title>Internal Server Error</title>\r\n        <style>\r\n            body {\r\n    font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;\r\n    font-size: .813em;\r\n    color: #222;\r\n    background-color: #fff;\r\n}\r\n\r\nh1, h2, h3, h4, h5 {\r\n    /*font-family: 'Segoe UI',Tahoma,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;*/\r\n    font-weight: 100;\r\n}\r\n\r\nh1 {\r\n    color: #44525e;\r\n    margin: 15px 0 15px 0;\r\n}\r\n\r\nh2 {\r\n    margin: 10px 5px 0 0;\r\n}\r\n\r\nh3 {\r\n    color: #363636;\r\n    margin: 5px 5px 0 0;\r\n}\r\n\r\ncode {\r\n    font-family: Consolas, \"Courier New\", courier, monospace;\r\n}\r\n\r\nbody .titleerror {\r\n    padding: 3px 3px 6px 3px;\r\n    display: block;\r\n    font-size: 1.5em;\r\n    font-weight: 100;\r\n}\r\n\r\nbody .location {\r\n    margin: 3px 0 10px 30px;\r\n}\r\n\r\n#header {\r\n    font-size: 18px;\r\n    padding: 15px 0;\r\n    border-top: 1px #ddd solid;\r\n    border-bottom: 1px #ddd solid;\r\n    m…",
 status: 500,
 ok: false,
 statusText: "Internal Server Error",
 headers: {…},
 type: 2,
 url: "http://localhost:62319/api/taller/cliente/" 
}
```

Comment: Si no entiendo mal tu codigo, estas ya resolviendo la promesa con `.then(this.extractData)` asi que, despues de eso ya no estas devolviendo una promesa si no `return body || {};` . Asi que este codigo  
`this.mensaje.then(response => {
        alert(response);
    }).catch(e => {
        console.log(e);
    });` te sobraria.

Comment: Hola gracias por tu ayuda, siguiendo con tu explicacion puse lo siguiente: alert(this.mensaje) y lo que me muestra es:  [object Promise]

Comment: Primero: Lo que dice @IkerObregonReigosa es incorrecto. Aunque la promesa se resuelva, siempre se esta devolviendo una promesa: lo que se devuelva con `return body || {}` se envolverá en una promesa tal cual @julio-segura tiene en su codigo, sino TypeScript se lo diría.

Comment: Segundo: Si el programa se te va al `catch` es porque hay algun error. ¿Qué es lo que te muestra el `console.log(e);`?

Comment: Hola @NeryOrtez acabo de hacer una edicion a la pregunta donde incluí lo que dice el console.log, ya que no me dejaba ponerla acá porque excedía el límite de carácteres

Answer (score 0):

No hay nada malo con tu código. El problema en realidad está en tu servidor, hay un error interno, revisar el log del servidor.